# In rails 3 and rspec 2, how can I test the layout used by a call to render()?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to test that a view was rendered with a given layout. How can I test which layout was used for the call to render() ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

David Chelimsky posted a good answer over on the [Ruby Forum](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/216851):

```
response.should render_template("layouts/some_layout")
```